# How to perform Auth0 JWT token user Role-based authorization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, auth0, jwt

I'm writing Spring Boot REST API, and I'm using JWT tokens. Now, I'm trying to create role-based authorization.

This is the tutorial/implementation that I'm using.

```
https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/
```

I expanded this implementation with additional Role entity, and added @ManyToMany mapping to ApplicationUser Entity.

Now, as far as I understands, user roles should be added to token (during its creation).
So, this is an existing code:

```
@Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {


        String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
```

I guess user roles should be added there. There is a function:

```
withArrayClaim(String Name, String[] items)
```

And there's my first problem: I'm not sure how to properly add this.

Then, is this fragments, which as far as I understand is place where token is verified:

```
private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What's bother me is fragment:

```
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
```

I don't understand why there is null (Inteliij highlights it as 'credentials') and this new ArrayList. Is there a place, where I should fetch roles from token, and add them?

I know, it's kinda broad scope question, but i couldn't find other solutions.
Or mayby there is an easier way to create simple JWT token authenitcation/authorization (role based).

Looking forward for your answers!

EDIT:

Or mayby is there more simple solutioni - not keeping user roles inside key - but only adding them in this 'second' part where null and new ArrayList is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the granted authorities based in the user roles and authenticate the user with it. Then the authenticated user principal will contain the roles. 
Simple example:

```
UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findUserByEmail(user); // this depends of course on your implementation
if (userEntity == null) return null;
List<RoleEntity> roles = userEntity.getRoles();
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
roles.forEach((role) -> {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
});
return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
```

Even better, you can create a UserPrincipal that implements UserDetails from spring security.

```
public class UserPrincipal implements UserDetails {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final UserEntity userEntity;

public UserPrincipal(UserEntity userEntity){
    this.userEntity = userEntity;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    // Get user Roles
    Collection<RoleEntity> roles = userEntity.getRoles();

    if(roles == null) return authorities;

    roles.forEach((role) -> {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    });

    return authorities;
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.userEntity.getEncryptedPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.userEntity.getEmail();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}
}
```

And to use it:

```
UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findUserByEmail(user);
if (userEntity == null) return null;

UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(userEntity);
  return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, userPrincipal.getAuthorities());
```

Comment: Hi, mayby you know, where the problem may be: trying to fetch user by username always throws NullPointerException (inside getAuthentication function (second function from my post)). Getting user by username is working, couse when im trying to access it via endpoint, user is returned correctly.

Comment: @Nickname11 I think I didn't understand the differences between the two cases. In your getAuthentication function what is user? is it username that is fetched from the JWT token? And then when you do a findByUsername it throws a null pointer exception? maybe you can post a new question

Comment: Yes, is exactly as you wrote. Im sure that findByUsername function is working -> couse it returns correct value, but only when im using it in different place (i'm testing it in endpoint).

Comment: Perhaps your userRepository is not being injected into your class? Then it's always null. I think that is a good explanation.

Comment: Hey, I created new post with this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030338/spring-boot-jwt-token-role-based-authorization-issue

Comment: @Nickname11 I answered it. Let me know if you have questions